# Validating External Data

Tags: php, validation

Below is an example of validation for user input from a form of a first name.

First name is **Craig** and must be max 40 characters.

```
// Check if not empty, type and not numeric
if (!empty($firstName) && is_string($firstName) && !is_numeric($firstName)) {
    echo 'in fn passed 1 ' . '<hr />';
}
else {
    echo 'in fn failed 1 ' . '<hr />';
}

// Check length
if ((strlen($firstName) > 1) && (strlen($firstName) < 41)) {
    echo 'in fn passed 2 ' . '<hr />';
}
else {
    echo 'in fn failed 2 ' . '<hr />';
}

// Accepts anything as long as it has a letter even if it contains < INJECTION RISK             
if (preg_match('/[a-z]/', $firstName)) {
     echo 'in fn passed 3 ' . '<hr />';
}
else {
     echo 'in fn failed 4 ' . '<hr />';
}
```

My question is if I use the above for user input from a form should I have the same validation for database data and session data or am I over doing it.

From what I know it's all external data so the same would apply but I've seen so many examples where database and session data are treated differently I have a doubt.

Could someone please let me know what would be considered an adequate secure method of validating this first name from a form and if the same method should be used on database and session data.

Many thanks.
Craig.

Comment: Your data on the database is probably limited by the field definition for length.  Also the data must get on there somehow, so unless people randomly add data using SQL, then you can validate it as it's loaded.  So fetching data from the database should already be valid.

Comment: What would happen if someone named "Mr. Peacock" appeared on your site? Also anyone with numbers or other unicode characters (e. g. ü) on their names won't be able to register. Thus the best thing for you to perform escaping of characters prior DB insertion. When retrieving values you shouldn't need any escaping, as it was done already at that point.

Comment: Nigel and Antonio - Thats great guys, its been bugging me for ages. My common sense is that even though it's external data the fact that I validated it before inserting it should negate the need to validate it again. (My doubt came from if someone tampered with the database itself but you've confirmed for me, don't worry)

Comment: @Antonio - You have picked up on another issue if someone registered with the unicode character ü which is why I would not include the preg_match check on this application. But I'm not sure what you mean about escaping the ü character prior DB insertion to address, could you please expand. Many thanks.

Comment: Sure, what I actually meant was that it would be far beneficial for you to escape characters inserted by users instead of limiting the options they have when typing values. For example, someone might try a SQL Injection inserting the following statement in an input: 'admin' or '1' = '1'. The DB will interpret the 1=1 segment as true and return all values stored on the target table. By escaping and sanitizing the input you won't have to worry about this because MySQL will interpret the input as a string

Comment: Thanks Antonio - I nearly understand but still not quite there. I'm aware of the SQL injection 1=1 risk and I'm using the CakePHP framework which I believe uses prepared statements which I believe eliminates this risk (Hopefully!) Are you referring to the PHP function    mysqli_real_escape_string() as seen here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Yes, that was the old way input was cleared out for DB, but today you should use an API for performing interactions with you database for further code abstraction and security. And CakePHP has a pretty robust system for validating and sanitizing data (they even state that in their homepage).